# Amazon Amplify how to make stage deployment and prod deployment using the same redirects and rewrites rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm using Amazon Amplify to deploy my application. Since I have a stage deployment and a prod deployment, I have 2 URLs.

Stage deployment:
[image]

Prod deployment:
[image]

Rewrites and redirects:
[image]

The issue: I cannot apply this rule to my stage domain. Therefore, once I open the stage domain there will be no background images and icons, If I put the build into the prod domain I would have icons and background images back. So how can I make my stage and prod domains using the same rule?